# How can I disable driver signature enforcement in Windows 8 in Parallels on Mac?

Tags: macos, windows-8, usb, parallels

How can I disable driver signature enforcement in Windows 8 in Parallels on Mac?

I can't find the PC settings `General` option on Mac.

I need to disable it to use a special USB driver.

Comment: The same way you do it in windows 7, what has your research shown?

Comment: I cannot do the following command on parallels

Win + C
it doesn't work so I can't access windows settings

Comment: So access it through Control Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 steps to disable the driver enforcement signature are different than for windows 8.1

Follow this tutorial
[Click here](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)